# funciones con parametros ilimitados en javascript

Tags: javascript, parametros

¿es posible añadir parametros ilimitados a una funcion?

```
  function sumar(valor1,valor2){
  return valor1+valor2;
  }
  var t=sumar(12,34,15);
```

¿sera posible o solo es el maximo que le especifiques?

Comment: Ees posible revisa el [revisa el objeto arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/arguments)

Comment: Hola. Existe una sintaxis para declarar funciones que admiten un número indeterminado de parámetros **[Parametros Rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/Parametros_rest)**

Comment: Una observación a **ilimitados**: En la [referencia de funciones](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones) dice taxativamente: `Una función puede tener hasta 255 argumentos.`

Answer (score 3):

el operador rest si claro que se puede (si te refieres a pasar multiples objetos como argumentos)! a diferencia de el operador de spread, rest toma multiples elementos (ejemplo los argumentos que le pasas a una funcion cuando la invocas) y los condensa en una sola variable -> cuando llames a ese argumento que almacena esos valores encontraras te retornara un array de esos elementos, en el ejemplo que te doy le paso a una funcion diferentes objetos de tipo number

```js
const sum = (...rest) => { 
  console.log('recibe ', rest);
}
sum(12, 33, 403, 30, 4, 10, 70);
```